# Writing hypothesis for linear multiple regression models

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, interpretation

I struggle writing hypothesis because I get very much confused by reference groups in the context of regression models.

For my example I'm using the `mtcars` dataset. The predictors are `wt`(weight), `cyl`(number of cylinders), and `gear`(number of gears), and the outcome variable is `mpg` (miles per gallon).

Say all your friends think you should buy a 6 cylinder car, but before you make up your mind you want to know how 6 cylinder cars perform miles-per-gallon-wise compared to 4 cylinder cars because you think there might be a difference.

Would this be a fair **null hypothesis** (since 4 cylinder cars is the reference group)?:
There is no difference between 6 cylinder car miles-per-gallon performance and 4 cylinder car miles-per-gallon performance.

Would this be a fair model **interpretation**?:
6 cylinder vehicles travel fewer miles per gallon (p=0.010, β -4.00, CI -6.95 - -1.04) as compared to 4 cylinder vehicles when adjusting for all other predictors, thus rejecting the null hypothesis.

Sorry for troubling, and thanks in advance for any feedback!

```
# Data 
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$cyl)) 
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$gear))

# Model   
mtcars.lm <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + gear, data = mtcars)

# Model output
library(sjPlot)
tab_model(mtcars.lm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you already got the right answer to both of your questions.

1. **Your null hypothesis in completely fair.** You did it the right way. When you have a factor variable as predictor, you omit one of the levels as a reference category (the default is usually the first one, but you also can change that). Then all your other levels’ coefficients are tested for a significant difference compared to the omitted category. Just like you did.

If you would like to compare 6-cylinder cars with 8-cylinder car, then you would have to change the reference category. In your hypothesis you just could had added at the end (or as a footnote): "when adjusting for weight and gear", but it is fine the way you did it.

2. **Your model interpretation is correct**: It is perfect the way you did it. You could even had said: "the best estimate is that 6 cylinder vehicles travel 4 miles per gallon less than 4 cylinder vehicles (p-value: 0.010; CI: -6.95, -1.04), when adjusting for weight and gear, thus rejecting the null hypothesis".

Let's assume that your hypothesis was related to gears, and you were comparing 4-gear vehicles with 3-gear vehicles. Then your result would be β: 0.65; p-value: 0.67; CI: -2.5, 3.8. You would say that: "There is no statistically significant difference between three and four gear cars in fuel consumption, when adjusting for weight and engine power, thus failing to reject the null hypothesis".